# Is the following considered micro optimization

Tags: javascript

I am not very well parsed in javascript, but do you call the following micro optimization?

```
for(var j=0;j < document.getElementsByTagName('a').length; j++)
{
  //...
}

var Elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
var ElementsLength = Elements.length;
for(var j=0;j < ElementsLength ; j++)
{
  //...
}

var Elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var j=0;j < Elements.length; j++)
{
  //...
}
```

- does document.getElementByTagName really get called in every loop
  cycle in the first case?
- do browsers try to optimize the javascript we write?
- is there any difference between the second and third case considering
  that the collection will never change?

Comment: Modern browsers will optimize it. So it wont make much difference. Although prefer the 2nd/3rd way (as given above) of writing this.

Comment: Recommend jsperf.com for testing performance :)

Comment: @vivek_nk I would not count on DOM query optimizations like that - #2 is definitely the one to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> does document.getElementByTagName really get called in every loop cycle in the first case?

Yes.

> do browsers try to optimize the javascript we write?

It won't change it *functionally*. There's a difference between calling a function once and calling it every time in a loop; perhaps you *meant* to call the function every time. "Optimising" that away is actually changing what the program does.

> is there any difference between the second and third case considering that the collection will never change?

Not functionally, but performance wise yes. Accessing the `length` attribute is a little more overhead than reading the number from a simple variable. Probably not so much you'd really notice, but it's there. It's also a case that cannot be optimised away, since `Elements.length` *may* change on each iteration, which would make the program behave differently. A good optimiser may be able to detect whether the attribute is ever changing and optimise in case it's certain it won't; but I don't know how many implementations really do that, because this can become quite complex.

Comment: Reading the `length` of a `NodeList` might involve even more overhead, since it will update the list.